# Is it possible to replace missing data if 50% of total data are missing?

Tags: mean, dataset, missing-data, data-imputation

In my study, 40K completed household surveys. However, when we suggested visiting a nearby health center to measure their physical parameters (height, weight, blood pressure, and blood glucose), only 20K visited. Is it possible to replace the unmeasured parameters of those who completed the household survey but did not measure their physical parameters? May we use mean imputation for unobserved data?

Comment: Sure you can, you can impute all missing data too, if you really wanted. The question is whether this is a good idea, and this is much harder to answer and data dependent. Maybe you could do some sensitivity analysis, this might give you some clue.

Comment: Mean imputation is *definitely* not a good idea, because you will severely underestimate variability. I would suggest looking into multiple imputation if you go ahead with this. The more important question is whether the data is missing (completely) at random, e.g. are these subjects that just happened to be busy that day, or is there a mechanism related to the outcome driving the missingness (for example, they are ashamed of their large weight or poor glucose control and don't want to get it measured).

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to replace the unmeasured parameters of those who completed the household survey but did not measure their physical parameters?

Yes, it is certainly possible.

> May we use mean imputation for unobserved data?

No that would be a very bad idea and will definitely create many biases. A much better approach would be to use Multiple Imputation (MI), which works well when you know the associations (ideally causal) between your variables. MI is a statistical technique used to handle missing data by creating several different plausible imputed datasets and then averaging the results. A rule of thumb is to compute as many imputations as there is missingness, so if you have 50% missingness, you use 50 imputations. These are then pooled using Rubin's Rules.

One key point with MI is the mechanism behind the missing data:

**Missing Completely at Random (MCAR)**: The probability of missingness is the same for all cases, meaning that the missing data is independent of both observed and unobserved data. In other words, the missingness has no relationship with any values in the dataset, whether missing or observed.

**Missing at Random (MAR):** The probability of missingness is related to the observed data but not the missing data. That is, the cause of the missingness can be explained by variables where you have complete information.

**Missing Not at Random (MNAR):** The probability of missingness is related to the unobserved data. This means that the missing values themselves influence the probability of missingness.

Providing that the missingness mechanism is either MCAR or MAR, then MI should work quite well. You would need to try to understand why your respondents failed to attend the health centre.

Given that 50% is a lot of missingness, I would suggest conducting  sensitivity analysis too.